# Aggregate daily to monthly data and calculate the delta mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi All I have a result from mysql that looks like this:

```
+---------------------+------+
|      timestamp      | data |  
+---------------------+------+
| 2015-06-01 04:25:18 |   10 |  
| 2015-06-15 04:25:18 |   20 |  
| 2015-06-30 04:25:18 |   30 |  
| 2015-07-01 04:25:18 |   50 |  
| 2015-07-15 04:25:18 |   60 |  
| 2015-07-30 04:25:18 |   70 |  
| 2015-08-01 04:25:18 |   80 |  
| 2015-08-15 04:25:18 |   90 |  
| 2015-08-30 04:25:18 |  100 |  
+---------------------+------+
```

I can use a query to work out the delta so it is like this:

```
+---------------------+------+------+
|      timestamp      | data | delta |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 2015-06-01 04:25:18 |   10 |    0 |
| 2015-06-15 04:25:18 |   20 |   10 |
| 2015-06-30 04:25:18 |   30 |   10 |
| 2015-07-01 04:25:18 |   50 |   20 |
| 2015-07-15 04:25:18 |   60 |   10 |
| 2015-07-30 04:25:18 |   70 |   10 |
| 2015-08-01 04:25:18 |   80 |   10 |
| 2015-08-15 04:25:18 |   90 |   10 |
| 2015-08-30 04:25:18 |  100 |   10 |
+---------------------+------+------+
```

And what I am after is a grouping of the delta column by month:

```
+-------+-------------+
| month | consumption |
+-------+-------------+
| 6/15  |          20 |
| 7/15  |          40 |
| 8/15  |          30 |
+-------+-------------+
```

I thought I had to try GROUP BY MONTH(timestamp) but it does not aggregate the deltas.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

to clarify the delta is a calculated column here is a modified query to show you what i mean:

```
 SELECT 
node_time,
   node_read - @prev AS delta,
  @prev := waveflow_data.node_read
FROM
  meter_data
INNER JOIN waveflow_data ON meter_data.node_address = waveflow_data.node_address 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev := (SELECT node_read FROM waveflow_data ORDER BY `node_time` DESC LIMIT 1)) variable_initialization_query_alias
WHERE
   meter_data.node_address = '10164E998976' 
ORDER BY waveflow_data.`node_time` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `sum(delta)` like below:

```
select time_stamp,sum(delta) as Consumption from test 
        group by month(time_stamp);
```

Check [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a1f53/3)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the final result from the initial given set of data then you can do as

```
select
date_format(timestamp,'%m/%y') as month,
sum(delta) as delta 
from
(
  select
  timestamp,
  data,
  @diff:= if(@prev=0,0,(data - @prev)) as delta,
  @prev:= data
  from table_name,(select @prev:=0)x 
  order by timestamp
)x
group by month;
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90a14/7)**

Answer (score 0):

Say if you have a query like, `Select timestamp,data,delta from mytable groupby timestamp`

update it to `Select  DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%m/%y') as timestamp,data,delta from mytable groupby timestamp`

The timestamp would now be in your desired format and grouping would automatically be done based on that.

Comment: When I try that it changes the date format but still does not aggregate the delta. I think this is because the delta is calculated in the query and not an actual column in the database

Comment: Yes it might be the case but I do no much about the pointer you have used, you need to update the inner query in join.